# Take and Group By in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I need to take (for example, 2), 2 messages from a conversation

example:

id = idConversation

```
Id | messageId | Message
---|-----------|--------
1  | 1         | "asd"
1  | 2         | "asd2"
1  | 3         | "asd3"
1  | 4         | "asd4"
2  | 5         | "asd5"
3  | 6         | "asd6"
3  | 7         | "asd7"
3  | 8         | "asd8"
3  | 9         | "asd9"
3  | 10        | "asd10"
4  | 11        | "asd11"
4  | 12        | "asd12"
4  | 13        | "asd13"
```

and i want that

```
Id   messageId   Message
---|-----------|--------
1  | 1         | "asd"
1  | 2         | "asd2"
2  | 5         | "asd5"
3  | 6         | "asd6"
3  | 7         | "asd7"
4  | 11        | "asd11"
4  | 12        | "asd12"
```

i can grouby idConversation, but i cant limit quantity using grouby in a conversation.

```
var test = unitOfWork.ChatMensagemRepository.GetAll()
                  .Where(x => x.PessoaCodigoPessoa == codigoRemetente)
                  .GroupBy(x => x.ChatConversaCodigoChatConversa)
                  .Select(group => new
                  {
                      codigoChat = group.Key,
                      list = group.Select(mensagem => new
                      {
                          // do stuff
                      })
                  }).ToList();
```

this is ok... but dont limit my list, when i do group.take(2).Select.....
give me "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

```
var test = unitOfWork.ChatMensagemRepository.GetAll()
                  .Where(x => x.PessoaCodigoPessoa == codigoRemetente)
                  .GroupBy(x => x.ChatConversaCodigoChatConversa)
                  .Select(group => new
                  {
                      codigoChat = group.Key,
                      list = group.Take(2).Select(mensagem => new
                      {
                          // do stuff
                      })
                  }).ToList();
```

error : Subquery returns more than 1 row

```
var test = unitOfWork.ChatMensagemRepository.GetAll()
                  .Where(x => x.PessoaCodigoPessoa == codigoRemetente)
                  .GroupBy(x => x.ChatConversaCodigoChatConversa)
                  .Select(group => new
                  {
                      codigoChat = group.Key,
                      list = group.Select(mensagem => new
                      {
                          // do stuff
                      }).take(2)
                  }).ToList();
```

error : Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Maybe show us what you *can* do

Comment: how do you decide who from the group `Id==1` is the bad kid who is not allowed to play with the others?=!

Comment: i will show, one minute

Comment: edited: when i put .take(number) on mensagens, i get   Message "null reference." string

Comment: @Strawberry
when i put .take after mensagem1 i get
"Subquery returns more than 1 row"}

Comment: You can solve the problem using a subquery for taking max N rows from your group. Searching about sql based solutions might be helpful.

Comment: updated my question with more examples

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I think you're after.  This query will return the top 3 sudtents by GPA in each class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ef6Test
{

    class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Class{ get; set; }

        public decimal GPA { get; set; }
    }

    class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                var q = db.Students
                         .GroupBy(s => s.Class)
                         .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(s => s.GPA).Take(3));

                Console.WriteLine(q.ToString());

                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +  InnerException {"Subquery returns more than 1 row"} System.Exception {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException}

Comment: I Dunno.  That query pattern works for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and is working fine:

```
class Conversation
{
    public int Id;
    public string Message;
    public int MessageId;
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inputList = new List<Conversation>
        {
            new Conversation() {Id = 1, Message = "asd0", MessageId = 1},
            new Conversation() {Id = 1, Message = "asd1", MessageId = 2},
            new Conversation() {Id = 1, Message = "asd2", MessageId = 3},
            new Conversation() {Id = 2, Message = "asd3", MessageId = 4},
            new Conversation() {Id = 2, Message = "asd4", MessageId = 5},
            new Conversation() {Id = 2, Message = "asd5", MessageId = 6},
            new Conversation() {Id = 3, Message = "asd6", MessageId = 7}
        };

        var outputList = inputList.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
            .SelectMany(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.MessageId).Take(2).ToList())
            .ToList();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you use `SelectMany` you can flatten the list down to a collection of the proper items

Comment: +  InnerException {"Subquery returns more than 1 row"} System.Exception {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException}

Comment: @AntonioHenrique I updated the answer

Comment: @Mhd dont working, I updated my question with more examples